# How do I handle returning to the previous page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

How do I handle returning to the previous page in Flutter?
If I did `Navigator.push`, how to perform some actions *when second page gets closed*?

Answer (score 0):

You "await" for the page to "pop"

```
Future<void> pushScreenAndDoSomething(BuildContext context)async{
    await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('YourPage');
    print('This executes after the screen is destroyed');

    //you can also get a result 
    String p = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('YourPage');
    //Inside your page, you Navigator.of(context).pop('DATA');
    print(p); //it should print DATA
  }
```